# Size of ellipsis

Tags: c

What is the size of ellipsis in C? I mean, what is the value of `sizeof(...)`?

Answer (score 5):

That's not a valid expression. `...` simply means the caller can pass in more arguments than the number of parameters the function formally specifies.